# Creating a Bash array with elements that have whitespaces in them

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I fail to understand what is happening between these two array creation, tested on cygwin GNU bash

```
$ array=('hello world' how are you)
$ echo $array
'hello world'    <----- This is expected
```

EDIT : As chepner pointed it out the output is

```
hello world      <----- no ''
```

Now with variable assignment as an intermediate step

```
$ words="'hello world' how are you"
$ echo $words
'hello world' how are you
$ array=($words)
$ echo $array
'hello           <----- Why was it split with ' '?
```

Comment: As an aside: the line marked with `<----- This is expected` is not actually what you get: The single quotes have _syntactic_ function and are therefore _removed_ by the shell, so the actual output is: `hello world` (no enclosing single quotes).

Comment: Use `declare -p array` to get a better idea of what is actually being created in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[codeforester's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44315992/45375) explains the issue well.

As for **a *solution***:

**Note: If the input you're dealing with doesn't actually have *embedded* quoting to demarcate elements, simply use `readarray -t array < <(...)` *as is***, where (`...`) represents the output-producing **command whose *lines* should be captured as the individual elements of an array**.

`xargs` generally understands shell quoting in literal input (except for *escaped, embedded* quotes):

```
words="'hello world' how are you"
echo "$words" | xargs -n 1 printf '%s\n'
hello world
how
are
you
```

Note how `hello world` was recognized as a *single* argument, and how its enclosing `'` instances were *removed*.

To utilize this when creating an array in `bash` (assumes Bash 4.x due to `readarray`, but it's possible to make it work in Bash 3.x<sup>[1]</sup>
):

```
words="'hello world' how are you"
readarray -t array < <(xargs -n 1 printf '%s\n' <<<"$words")
declare -p array
```

which yields:

```
declare -a array=([0]="hello world" [1]="how" [2]="are" [3]="you")
```

(The enclosing `"` instances are an artifact of the `declare -p` output format - they have *syntactic* function, if you were to reuse the output as shell *source code*.)

---

<sup>[1] A Bash v3+ solution, using `read` instead of `readarray`:

`words="'hello world' how are you"
 IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra array < <(xargs -n 1 printf '%s\n' <<<"$words")
 declare -p array`</sup>

Comment: This is great if you statically assign words="'hello world' how are you", but what if you're trying to do this with results of md5sum and filenames with spaces where the output would be: 2345asf32asdf some file name.txt

Comment: @spezticle: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

From Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

> ```
> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to
> referencing with a subscript of 0.
> ```

When you put single quotes inside double quotes as in:

```
words="'hello world' how are you"
```

the single quotes become a literal part of the string and hence won't prevent word split when you initialize the array with

```
array=($words)
```

wherein 0th element of the array would become `'hello`.  To prevent word splitting in this case, do this:

```
array=("$words")
```

However, that wouldn't achieve your intention of making `hello world` as the 0th element. The direct assignment `array=('hello world' how are you)` is the right way of doing it.

---

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [Word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: I see. I wanted to make an array with the output of a command array=$(command), but this problem arise. With the insight you gave me, i should be able to achieve this by assigning IFS=$'\n' in order to ignore ' '

Answer (score 0):

It's the dereferencing.  Try this:

```
$ array=('hello world' how are you)
$ echo $array
hello world
$ echo ${array[@]}
hello world how are you
$ echo ${array[0]}
hello world
$ echo ${array[1]}
how
$ echo ${array[2]}
are
$ echo ${array[3]}
you
```

Comment: I think my question was not clear, sorry. 
My desire is to understand why it's not the same array that's created when using a variable containing the string

Answer (score 0):

"Referring to the content of a member variable of an array without providing an index number is the same as referring to the content of the first element, the one referenced with index number zero."  From [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), last line of section 10.2.2

So

```
$ echo $array
```

is equivalent to

```
$ echo ${array[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case single quotes prevent word splitting to split hello world in two arguments, the single quotes are not echoed

```
$ array=('hello world' how are you)
$ echo $array
hello world
```

in the second, the quotes are string literal, arguments are split, this can't be seen because echo displays all arguments, if you use `printf "<%s>\n" $words` you will see better

```
$ words="'hello world' how are you"
$ echo $words
'hello world' how are you
$ array=($words)
$ echo $array
'hello         

$ words="'hello world' how are you"
$ printf "<%s>\n" $words
<'hello>
<world'>
<how>
<are>
<you>
```

As said in comments, eval is dangerous, you must know what you are doing

```
$ eval "array=($words)"
$ printf "<%s>\n" "${array[@]}"
<hello world>
<how>
<are>
<you>
```

Comment: Oh, so when assigning an array, quotes are special instructions ! I thought it was the character itself

Comment: it's not specific to array, it's the same for command parsing

Comment: command line parsing has many steps and after `variable expansion` special character generally loses there meaning to avoid injection, but the parsing can be done a more time with the `eval` builtin but this is why `eval` is called `evil` you have to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
$ array=($(echo -e $'a a\nb b' | tr ' ' '§')) && array=("${array[@]//§/ }") && echo "${array[@]/%/ INTERELEMENT}"

a a INTERELEMENT b b INTERELEMENT
```